# Have a problem when run jbmp sample in eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse, jbpm

Coud anybody help me fix my problem? When I tried to run jbpm sample in eclipse. This is code:

```
public class ProcessMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
    KieBase kbase = kContainer.getKieBase("kbase");

    RuntimeManager manager = createRuntimeManager(kbase);
    RuntimeEngine engine = manager.getRuntimeEngine(null);
    KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();
    ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello");

    manager.disposeRuntimeEngine(engine);
    System.exit(0);
}

private static RuntimeManager createRuntimeManager(KieBase kbase) {
    JBPMHelper.startH2Server();
    JBPMHelper.setupDataSource();
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.persistence.jpa");
    RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder builder = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
        .newDefaultBuilder().entityManagerFactory(emf)
        .knowledgeBase(kbase);
    return RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get()
        .newSingletonRuntimeManager(builder.get(), "com.sample:example:1.0");
}
```

}

Then, this is error in console window:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Driver class name cannot be empty.
at org.kie.test.util.db.internal.DatabaseProvider.fromDriverClassName(DatabaseProvider.java:32)
at org.kie.test.util.db.DataSourceFactory.setupPoolingDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:57)
at org.kie.test.util.db.DataSourceFactory.setupPoolingDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:42)
at org.jbpm.test.JBPMHelper.setupDataSource(JBPMHelper.java:103)
at com.sample.ProcessMain.createRuntimeManager(ProcessMain.java:34)
at com.sample.ProcessMain.main(ProcessMain.java:23)
```

Comment: Since it's not thrown from a method you're calling directory, the source for `org.kie.test.util.db.DataSourceFactory.` would be needed. Are you sure you're following the documentation for using that class correctly?

Comment: I think it shoud have worked. Because it is a available sample from JBPM Project.

Answer (score 0):

1. jBPMHelper no longer sets default values for H2,-  https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/commit/34293e9675ae4f36f2a3a9e633305bbcc8260d19
2. We need to use - PersistenceUtil.setupPoolingDataSource(); instead JBPMHelper.setupDataSource();
3. Also include datasource.properties file at resources folder.

datasource.properties - > https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-examples/src/main/resources/datasource.properties